# How do I pass arguments to a passport strategy callback using a bluebird promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, passport.js, bluebird

I’m trying to promisify [passport.js’s local strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). I'm new to both promises and passport, and I’m relying heavily on [this comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920589/how-to-pass-a-third-argument-to-a-callback-using-bluebird-js-nodeify), which deals with passing additional arguments to passport’s `done()` callback using bluebird’s Promise library. This comment resulted in a [new bluebird implementation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/219) that handles additional callback parameters, but I can’t get it working in my own code:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const NoMatchedUserError = require('../helpers/error_helper').NoMatchedUserError;
const NotActivatedError = require('../helpers/error_helper').NotActivatedError;

const localOptions = { usernameField: 'email' };
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function(email, password, done) {

  let user;

  User.findOne({ email: email }).exec()
    .then((existingUser) => {
      if (!existingUser) { throw new NoMatchedUserError('This is not a valid email address.'); }
      user = existingUser;
      return user.comparePassword(password, user.password);
    })
    .then((isMatch) => {
      if (!isMatch) { throw new NoMatchedUserError('This is not a valid password.'); }
       return user.isActivated();
    })
    .then((isActivated) => {
      if (!isActivated) { throw new NotActivatedError('Your account has not been activated.'); }
      return user;
    })
    .asCallback(done, { spread: true });
});
```

The user is able to validate without a problem. It’s authentication failure that I’m having an issue with: `done(null, false, { message: ‘message’}` obviously isn’t being called in the `.asCallback` method. I’m pretty sure it has to do with throwing an error, so instead I tried using this:

```
if (!existingUser) { return [ false, { message: 'This is not a valid email address.' } ]; }
```

But returning an array also doesn't work since it gets passed down the promise chain and breaks the code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any solution to this?